# Вывод в приложении под Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть задача сделать следующее:

На главном экране есть кнопки, при нажатии на которые открывается описание (другой фрагмент).

Вопрос: как лучше хранить эти описании? Они достаточно большие. И если можно, пример (если в xml файле и каком-то другом формате). Или лучше прописать в проге сразу?

И второй вопрос: для каждого нажатия кнопки лучше создавать новый фрагмент или просто менять на одном фрагменте данные?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хардкодить не рекомендую никогда.

1. Если описания статичны, то в файликах лучше. Удобно хранить в string.xml файлах, чтобы проще было локализовывать. Если слишком большие описания, то можно просто в assets положить, например, и оттуда потом считывать.
2. Если динамичные описания (могут иногда меняться), то тягать с сети, а потом склыдвать в файлик или SQLite.

> И второй вопрос: для каждого нажатия
> кнопки лучше создавать новый фрагмент
> или просто менять на одном фрагменте
> данные? Спасибо!

Лучше переиспользовать один фрагмент.